# JPA select association and use NamedEntityGraph

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

Our in-house framework built with Java 11, Spring Boot, Hibernate 5 and QueryDSL does a lot of auto-generation of queries. I try to keep everything efficient and load associations only when needed.
When loading full entities, the programmer can declare a NamedEntityGraph to be used. Now there is one case where a query like this is generated:

```
select user.groups
from User user
where user.id = ?1
```

Where the Entities in question look like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = User.ENTITY_GRAPH,
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(User.Fields.permissions),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = User.Fields.groups, subgraph = "user-groups-subgraph")
    },
    subgraphs = @NamedSubgraph(
        name = "user-groups-subgraph",
        attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(Group.Fields.permissions)
      }
    ))
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Permission.class)
  @CollectionTable(name = "USERS_PERMISSIONS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "uid"))
  private Set<Permission> permissions = EnumSet.of(Permission.ROLE_USER);
  
  @ManyToMany(fetch = LAZY)
  private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Group.ENTITY_GRAPH,
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = Group.Fields.permissions)
    })
public class Group {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;
  
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Permission.class)
  @CollectionTable(
      name = "GROUPS_PERMISSIONS",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gid")
  )
  @NonNull
  private Set<Permission> permissions = EnumSet.noneOf(Permission.class);
}
```

When selecting either User or Group directly, the generated query simply applies the provided NamedEntityGraphs. But for the above query the exception is:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException:
  query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
  [FromElement{explicit,collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=user,role=foo.bar.User.permissions,tableName={none},tableAlias=permission3_,origin=null,columns={,className=null}}]
```

I first tried the *User* graph, but since we are fetching Groups, I tried the *Group* graph. Same Exception.

Problem is, there is no easy way to add a `FETCH JOIN` to the generated query, since I don't know which properties of the association should be joined in anyway. I would have to load the Entitygraph, walk it and any subgraph and generated the right join clauses.

Some more details on Query generation:

```
// QueryDsl 4.3.x Expressions, where propType=Group.class, entityPath=User, assocProperty=groups
final Path<?> expression = Expressions.path(propType, entityPath, assocProperty);

// user.id = ?1
final BooleanExpression predicate = Expressions.predicate(Ops.EQ, idPath, Expressions.constant(rootId));

// QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor#createQuery from Spring Data JPA
final JPQLQuery<P> query = createQuery(predicate).select(expression).from(path);

// Add Fetch Graph
((AbstractJPAQuery<?, ?>) query).setHint(GraphSemantic.FETCH.getJpaHintName(), entityManager.getEntityGraph(fetchGraph));
```

**EDIT:**

I can reproduce this with a simple JPQL Query. It's very strange, if I try to make a typed query, it will select a List of Sets of Group and untyped just a  List of Group.
Maybe there is something conceptually wrong - I'm selecting a Collection and I'm trying to apply a fetch join on it. But JPQL doesn't allow a SELECT from a subquery, so I'm not sure what to change..

```
// em is EntityManager
List gs = em
                .createQuery("SELECT u.groups FROM User u WHERE u.id = ?1")
                .setParameter(1, user.getId())
                .setHint(GraphSemantic.FETCH.getJpaHintName(), em.getEntityGraph(Group.ENTITY_GRAPH))
                .getResultList();
```

Same Exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Comment: I doubt the snippet generates the mentioned JPQL fragment, because the exception specifically mentions that there is an unsupported join, and your expected query has no joins. Please provide the full query generation code and actual produced JPQL query.

Furthermore, QueryDSL does not handle EntityGraphs out of the box. How are you currently associating the EntityGraph to be used with the Query?

Comment: So I've added setting the Fetch Graph. It's indeed hidden away a bit, but you can set fetch hints. The join is not in the actual query, but defined by the Entity Graph (Fetch graphs are equivalent to fetch joins). I was able to reproduce the behavior with a test case using a simple JPQL query. I guess something is conceptually wrong here - like I actually want to apply the fetch graph to the members of the collection - but I'm can't figure it out.

Comment: Probably its trying to join `user.groups.permissions` which is not allowed. Can you change the query so that it projects `SELECT g FROM User user JOIN user.groups g`? (`FETCH JOIN g.permissions` should still be added to the query if the fetch plan is correctly applied). I know its possible to specify a fetch plan for a QueryDSL query, its just not officially supported and hard to do via the API - so I was mostly wondering if you did it in a proper way.

Comment: So I've tried what you suggested, but I got the Exception again. Looking at the details, i realized it tried to load User.permissions this time. Maybe the Entity Graph is applied to the root Entity only (User) and the properties happen to have the same name...
Explicitly writing `SELECT g FROM User u JOIN u.groups g LEFT JOIN FETCH g.permissions WHERE u.id = ?1` seems to work.

Comment: Maybe the fetch plan naively assumes that it is applied to the first join-node. If you insist in using the fetch plan, you could try rewriting your query to: `SELECT g FROM user.groups g`  or even `SELECT g FROM Group g WHERE g.user =...` (although here you might have to declare the inverse relation on the group class depending on your kind of query)

Comment: Right, if I rename the property I get an Exception: `QueryException: could not resolve property: groupPermissions of: a.b.c.User`. That's not good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218352/discussion-between-jan-willem-gmelig-meyling-and-benjamin-maurer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem can be distilled down to a resolution problem of the Entit Graphs attributes:

```
select user.groups
from User user
where user.id = ?1
```

With the Entity Graph

```
EntityGraph<Group> eg = em.createEntityGraph(Group.class);
eg.addAttributeNodes(Group.Fields.permissions);
```

Gives an Exception that shows that Hibernate tries to fetch `User.permissions` instead of `Group.permissions`. This is the [bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14113).

And there is another bug regarding the use of `@ElementCollection` [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14116).